# Assembly Version Mismatch error

Tags: asp.net, .net, gac, .net-assembly

i am running a Web Application which shows assembly mismatch error during loading. I looked into my hard drive and application path to find out the false assembly but i have the right version of assembly everywhere i.e. in GAC, My Application path and all.

Now i want to use fiddler or some other same kind of tool to trace out from where the false assembly is getting loaded and create problem. Is it possible with fiddler or there is some other tool available which can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).